# Retrieving the underlying dataitems of selected gridview rows

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a button on the page and a gridview with checkboxes on the first column. The gridview is bound to a List. On buttonClick, I need to retrieve the underlying bound data item (MyEntity) for each selected row.  How can I do this? I can't simply recreate MyEntity based on the gridview columns, because I am not displaying all the fields of MyEntity.  I need a way to get a hold of MyEntity based on the key (MyEntityId).

Answer (score 0):

store `MyEntityId` in a hidden field in your gridview,read this when you need to,  and then use this to select(LINQ `SingleOrDefault`) the corresponding object from your list that you bind to datasource.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("CheckBox1"); 
    HiddenField HiddenField1 = (HiddenField)gvrow.FindControl("HiddenField1")
    if (CheckBox1.Checked) 
    { 
        // your code to get the entity here 
    }     
}
```

something like that..